# HornetQ 2.4.0 dont replicated binding journal files on backup-server

Tags: replication, hornetq, journal

At first, sorry for my English)
We have RHEL 6.6, HornetQ 2.4.0 with live&backup configuration and queue with messages from 2 to 11 megabytes.
When backup server starting live node initiates replication on backup, but this process not ending and not droped whit error.

For example
Log on live server about initiates replication

```
[2015-05-05 17:27:32,587] [INFO ] [Thread-2] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ221025: Replication: sending JournalFileImpl: (hornetq-data-759.hq id = 192, recordID = 192) (size=10,485,760) to backup. NIOSequentialFile ../data/server0/data/messaging/journal/hornetq-data-759.hq
[2015-05-05 17:27:32,633] [INFO ] [Thread-2] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ221025: Replication: sending JournalFileImpl: (hornetq-data-749.hq id = 755, recordID = 755) (size=10,485,760) to backup. NIOSequentialFile ../data/server0/data/messaging/journal/hornetq-data-749.hq
[2015-05-05 17:27:32,675] [INFO ] [Thread-2] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ221025: Replication: sending JournalFileImpl: (hornetq-bindings-365.bindings id = 1, recordID = 1) (size=1,048,576) to backup. NIOSequentialFile ../data/server0/data/messaging/bindings/hornetq-bindings-365.bindings
[2015-05-05 17:27:32,686] [INFO ] [Thread-2] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ221025: Replication: sending JournalFileImpl: (hornetq-bindings-369.bindings id = 2, recordID = 2) (size=1,048,576) to backup. NIOSequentialFile ../data/server0/data/messaging/bindings/hornetq-bindings-369.bindings
[2015-05-05 17:27:32,689] [INFO ] [Thread-2] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ221025: Replication: sending JournalFileImpl: (hornetq-bindings-362.bindings id = 366, recordID = 366) (size=1,048,576) to backup. NIOSequentialFile ../data/server0/data/messaging/bindings/hornetq-bindings-362.bindings
```

Log pushing journal files on backup serever

```
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,558] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Creating file hornetq-data-190.hq
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,655] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Renaming file hornetq-data-190.hq.tmp as hornetq-data-190.hq
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,662] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Creating file hornetq-data-191.hq
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,722] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Renaming file hornetq-data-191.hq.tmp as hornetq-data-191.hq
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,723] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Creating file hornetq-data-774.hq
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,771] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Renaming file hornetq-data-774.hq.tmp as hornetq-data-774.hq
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,775] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Creating file hornetq-data-775.hq
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,826] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Renaming file hornetq-data-775.hq.tmp as hornetq-data-775.hq
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,826] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Creating file hornetq-data-776.hq
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,879] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Renaming file hornetq-data-776.hq.tmp as hornetq-data-776.hq
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,880] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] pushing openFile JournalFileImpl: (hornetq-data-776.hq id = 776, recordID = 776)
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,882] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Creating file hornetq-bindings-1.bindings
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,889] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Renaming file hornetq-bindings-1.bindings.tmp as hornetq-bindings-1.bindings
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,889] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Creating file hornetq-bindings-380.bindings
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,898] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Renaming file hornetq-bindings-380.bindings.tmp as hornetq-bindings-380.bindings
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,898] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Creating file hornetq-bindings-381.bindings
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,905] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Renaming file hornetq-bindings-381.bindings.tmp as hornetq-bindings-381.bindings
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,906] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Creating file hornetq-bindings-382.bindings
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,916] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] Renaming file hornetq-bindings-382.bindings.tmp as hornetq-bindings-382.bindings
[2015-05-05 18:56:15,917] [TRACE] [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-netty-threads-1442326569)] [org.hornetq.journal] pushing openFile JournalFileImpl: (hornetq-bindings-382.bindings id = 382, recordID = 382)
```

And starting backup server

```
[2015-05-06 11:16:26,919] [INFO ] [main] [org.hornetq.integration.bootstrap] HQ101000: Starting HornetQ Server
[2015-05-06 11:16:27,880] [INFO ] [main] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ221000: backup server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=true,backup=true,sharedStore=false,journalDirectory=../data/server0/data/messaging/journal,bindingsDirectory=../data/server0/data/messaging/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=../data/server0/data/messaging/largemessages,pagingDirectory=../data/server0/data/messaging/paging)
[2015-05-06 11:16:27,892] [WARN ] [HQ119000: Activation for server HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=null] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ222162: Moving data directory ../data/server0/data/messaging/bindings to ../data/server0/data/messaging/bindings12
[2015-05-06 11:16:27,893] [WARN ] [HQ119000: Activation for server HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=null] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ222162: Moving data directory ../data/server0/data/messaging/journal to ../data/server0/data/messaging/journal12
[2015-05-06 11:16:27,893] [WARN ] [HQ119000: Activation for server HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=null] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ222162: Moving data directory ../data/server0/data/messaging/paging to ../data/server0/data/messaging/paging12
[2015-05-06 11:16:27,893] [WARN ] [HQ119000: Activation for server HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=null] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ222162: Moving data directory ../data/server0/data/messaging/largemessages to ../data/server0/data/messaging/largemessages12
[2015-05-06 11:16:28,095] [INFO ] [HQ119000: Activation for server HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=null] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ221013: Using NIO Journal
[2015-05-06 11:16:28,140] [WARN ] [HQ119000: Activation for server HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=null] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ222007: Security risk! HornetQ is running with the default cluster admin user and default password. Please see the HornetQ user guide, cluster chapter, for instructions on how to change this.
[2015-05-06 11:16:28,166] [INFO ] [HQ119000: Activation for server HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=null] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ221043: Adding protocol support CORE
[2015-05-06 11:16:28,169] [INFO ] [HQ119000: Activation for server HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=null] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ221043: Adding protocol support STOMP
[2015-05-06 11:16:28,171] [INFO ] [HQ119000: Activation for server HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=null] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ221043: Adding protocol support AMQP
[2015-05-06 11:16:28,618] [INFO ] [HQ119000: Activation for server HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=null] [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ221109: HornetQ Backup Server version 2.5.0.SNAPSHOT (Wild Hornet, 124) [null] started, waiting live to fail before it gets active
```

hornetq-configuration.xml

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-configuration.xsd">

   <bindings-directory>${data.dir:../data}/server0/data/messaging/bindings</bindings-directory>
   <journal-directory>${data.dir:../data}/server0/data/messaging/journal</journal-directory>
   <large-messages-directory>${data.dir:../data}/server0/data/messaging/largemessages</large-messages-directory>
   <paging-directory>${data.dir:../data}/server0/data/messaging/paging</paging-directory>

   <shared-store>false</shared-store>
   <backup-group-name>hub_group</backup-group-name>
   <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
   <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
   <connection-ttl-override>100000</connection-ttl-override>
   <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
   <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
   <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
   <!-- Connectors -->

   <connectors>
      <connector name="netty-connector">
         <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
         <param key="port" value="5445"/>
         <param key="host" value="host1"/>
         <param key="tcp-send-buffer-size" value="524288"/>
         <param key="tcp-receive-buffer-size" value="524288"/>
      </connector>
   </connectors>

   <!-- Acceptors -->
   <acceptors>
      <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">
         <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
         <param key="port" value="5445"/>
         <param key="host" value="host1"/>
         <param key="tcp-send-buffer-size" value="524288"/>
         <param key="tcp-receive-buffer-size" value="524288"/>
      </acceptor>
   </acceptors>

   <!-- Clustering configuration -->

   <broadcast-groups>
      <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
         <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.9}</group-address>
         <group-port>9876</group-port>
         <broadcast-period>100</broadcast-period>
         <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
     </broadcast-group>
   </broadcast-groups>

   <discovery-groups>
      <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
         <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.9}</group-address>
         <group-port>9876</group-port>
         <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
      </discovery-group>
   </discovery-groups>

   <cluster-connections>
      <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
         <address>jms</address>
         <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
         <check-period>5000</check-period>
         <connection-ttl>10000</connection-ttl>
         <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
         <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
         <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
         <forward-when-no-consumers>true</forward-when-no-consumers>
         <max-hops>1</max-hops>
         <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
      </cluster-connection>
   </cluster-connections>
</configuration>
```

hornetq-jms.xml

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd">
    <!--the connection factory used by the example-->
    <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory">
        <connectors>
            <connector-ref connector-name="netty-connector"/>
        </connectors>
        <entries>
            <entry name="ConnectionFactory"/>
        </entries>
        <min-large-message-size>10240</min-large-message-size>
        <connection-ttl>5000</connection-ttl>
        <client-failure-check-period>5000</client-failure-check-period>
        <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
        <retry-interval-multiplier>1.5</retry-interval-multiplier>
        <max-retry-interval>60000</max-retry-interval>
        <reconnect-attempts>1000</reconnect-attempts>
        <consumer-window-size>0</consumer-window-size>
    </connection-factory>

   <queue name="DLQ">
      <entry name="/queue/DLQ"/>
   </queue>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Do not know what you are asking for

Comment: Hello, The problem is that he writes a journal file and nothing else happens. No event for replication to complete or error messages. In addition, according to the plan jconsole Hornet stops sending messages and from the Consumer fall off. This did not turn off if there is a backup server